# Cucumber Jenkins parametrisation

Tags: jenkins, testing, automation, cucumber

I'm wondering if it's possible to parameterised .feature in cucumber using Jenkins, for example:

> Scenario: Test
>
> Then Set login as "     " into main field

Using Jenkins I'd like to set in empty space specific login. In the same feature one time I'd like to set login as "Test2", other time when i run my test I'd like to set login as "Test"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for some templating mechanism here. Use apache velocity - java in order to create the template of your feature file and then in one stage of the jenkins pipeline, create the desired feature file with the required values using parameterization. Let me know if you still have any question.